# Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor in LLVM(Porting code from windows to mac)

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, compiler-errors, llvm

We are in the process of porting some c++ code from windows to mac and are having issues compiling it with LLVM 6.1 using c++11. We are encountering errors all over the place of "Call to implicitly-deleted copy contructor" Some of these errors are popping up in our code.

```
for (auto it : _unhandledFiles)//ERROR HERE
{
    if (it.first == file)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

However they are also showing up in the memory file of the LLVM compiler as well as the vector file.

```
template <class _Up, class... _Args>
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    void
    construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
    {
        ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);//ERROR HERE
    }


vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::operator=(const vector& __x)
{
if (this != &__x)
{
    __base::__copy_assign_alloc(__x);
    assign(__x.__begin_, __x.__end_);//ERROR HERE
}
return *this;
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced this error before when porting c++ code from Windows to Mac? I feel as if it is compiler related and there must be some simple fix that I am just unaware of as I'm getting errors in places I can't actually edit (memory, vector etc....)

Comment: What is the type of `_unhandledFiles`?  Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30850780/edit) your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are the things in `_unhandledFiles` copyable?

Comment: std::vector<FileInfo::FileNameInfo> _unhandledFiles;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is very ambiguous:

```
for (auto it : _unhandledFiles)//ERROR HERE
```

`auto` uses template argument deduction, so

```
std::string s;
std::string& sr = sr;
auto x = sr;
```

in the above code `x` is deduced to be of type `std::string`, not `std::string&`. So your loop is equivalent to:

```
for (_unhandledFiles::value_type it : _unhandledFiles)
// aka
for (auto uhfIt = _unhandledFiles.cbegin();
         uhfIt != _unhandledFiles.cend();
         ++uhfIt) {
    _unhandledFiles::value_type it = *uhfIt; // COPY
    // ... your code here ...
    it.dtor(); // obviously not, I'm just emphasizing.
}
```

not

```
for (_unhandledFiles::value_type& it : _unhandledFiles)
```

So each iteration of the loop is *copying* values from _unhandledFiles.

The fix would be to either use iterators or:

```
for (auto& it: _unhandledFiles)
---------^
```

---- edit ----

Because of the confusion this causes, C++14 introduces `decltype(auto)` but using that would introduce a copy if the rhs was not a reference.

```
std::string s;
std::string& sr = s;

auto xr1 = sr; // std::string xr1 -> copy
auto& xr2 = sr; // std::string& xr2 -> reference
decltype(auto) xr3 = sr; // std::string& xr3 -> reference

auto xv1 = s; // std::string xv1 -> copy
auto& xv2 = s; // std::string& xv2 -> reference
decltype(auto) xv3 = s; // std::string xv3 -> copy
```

Comment: Did you mean `std::string& sr = sr`?

Comment: Replacing the for loop with the following fixed the issue. for (std::vector<FileInfo::FileNameInfo>::iterator it = _unhandledFiles.begin(); it != _unhandledFiles.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->first == file)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

Comment: @JulianHunt If that worked, `for (auto& it: _unhandledFiles)` would also fix it. Added this to the answer, since I hadn't already. I need a lot more coffee this morning.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, strange how just changing compilers seems to break so much... Not sure why my question got downvoted... But thanks for the help!

Comment: @JulianHunt your question was probably downvoted because you didn't include nearly enough information to solve your problem.  kfsone basically had to read your mind and guess what caused your problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- the goal in asking a "why doesn't this work" question should be to produce a MINIMAL snippet of code *that reproduces your error* all by itself.